# Why I am getting this error: object has no attribute 'astype'

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have defined a function `myfunc` inside a python file `myfile`. when i import this function from a jupyter notebook, it is showing the following error:

```
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.misc import imread
import ast
from myfile import myfunc
 .....
class_mask = np.equal(image, i)
class_mask = class_mask.astype(np.float32)
 .....
AttributeError: 'NotImplementedType' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

However, whenever I have the `myfile` content in a cell and running inside the jupyter, it is working without any problem? What is the reason for this error? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can only import function from a python module/file. A Jupyter Notebook when you save have an extention of `.pynb`, that means its not actually a python module.

Just open your Notebook with a text editor, you probably see html like content. Which is not possible for a python module to contain.

You rather want to export the Jupyter Notebook as Python Module in the same directory from where you are trying to run your current program.

> File -> Export as Python File

Once exported you can use it as just any other python module. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your comment, my code is in a python file not jupyter, and the python code and jupyter module are in the same directory that I am trying to import and call it from a jupyter code.

Comment: Try from myfile import myfile.myfunc